# Driven harmonic oscillator: driving constant force is only temporary

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Example: Let $m$ be a point mass that hangs at the equilibrium point $y_0$ on a spring fixed at the end. No damping force acts on the particle. Let $k$ be the spring constant.

If I want to calculate $y(t)$ I can use newton's second law to get: $m\cdot y''(t)=m\cdot g -k\cdot y$ or $y''(t)+\omega_0^2\cdot y=g$ with $\omega_0^2=\frac{k}{m}$

Homogeneous solution: $y_h(t)=acos(\omega_0\cdot t)+bsin(\omega_0\cdot t)$

Particular solution: $y_p(t)=\frac{g}{\omega_0^2}$

$\rightarrow y(t)=acos(\omega_0\cdot t)+bsin(\omega_0\cdot t) + \frac{g}{\omega_0^2}$

But what if a constant force $F$ acts in the same direction as $ m\cdot g $ between $t = 0$ and $t = t^*$  . So F is only a temporary force.

How can I express such a case in a differential equation? I would prefer to get just a hint so I can find a way myself.

My thoughts:

I tried stuff like: $y''(t)+\omega_0^2\cdot y=g+\frac{F}{m}$ but after $t^*$  the constant driving force $F$ does not act anymore (that's how I interpret it) so my equation seems wrong to me.

I almost have the feeling like I need two differential equations, one between $t = 0$ and $t = t^*$ and the other for $t > t^*$.

I assume that the system is in the rest position for $t = 0$  so that  $y(0)=y_0$.
And that the constant force $F$ determines how high the amplitude is, since there is no damping force the amplitude $A$ would equal $y(t^*)$.

Comment: For numerical simulation you can use the Step(t,ts) Function  , for t < ts step=0 else step=1, so in your case you multiply F by 1-step(t-ts)

Answer (score 0):

You could for example, as suggested by @Eli, Heaviside function for t=t*. But you can as one does en other problems, divide the problem en two regions, one before and one after, and then demand continuity of the solution and the first derivative. Your particle is not going to disappear when the force stops and it is not going to jump either once is gone.